# Is it possible to have hot reload with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get into the way of things with the Kubernetes but I'm facing a problem with hot reload.

In the development mode when I am just working on the code and I need the code be synchronized with the pods directly like in Docker when I use volumes to keep the state.

Is there any chance to make it work with the Kubernetes?

I would be thankful for any help with Kubernetes...

Comment: Do you mean you want to refresh code in the pod and restart your process to make the code work in the pod?

Comment: @vincentpli yeah, I am new to Kubernetes so It's quite puzzling for me at the moment. Everywhere I can see the example of how the use prepared docker images and operate with them. I want to grasp two things now: AWS infrastrusture and Kubernetes. So far as I umderstand I should work with a single microservice running on docker image (I am using docker volumes there to get hot reloads) and after that I am pushing the code and CI on the background prepares the image and pushes it to EKS or ECS and the last sends it to EKS. Am I right?

Comment: From the view of Cloud native(or kubernetes), the infrastructure is immutable and the Pods are the smallest deployable units.
So you should replace the pod rather than change it(your code is part of the pod/image).
so the correct process is:
change code -> build image -> recreate pod in your env

But actually, your process still could work just not follow the best practice of cloud native...

Comment: @vincentpli thank you for your responce. Yeah, I don't have much experience here. All this DevOps stuff is a bit tricky.  I have one more question. Maybe you know better... how can I reuse my .env file with Docker and Kubernetes? With Kubernetes I can generate it as a Secret Generator --from-file=. What about Docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the view of Cloud native(or kubernetes), the infrastructure is immutable and the Pods are the smallest deployable units. So you should replace the pod rather than change it(your code is part of the pod/image). so the correct process is: change code -> build image -> recreate pod in your env But actually, your process still could work just not follow the best practice of cloud native... –
> vincent pli

Also, you can try [Ksync](https://github.com/ksync/ksync), that allows you to synchronize application code between your local and Kubernetes cluster. Kindly ask you to refer to [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/01/developing-on-kubernetes/#ksync) to read more about.